# Cannot call AJAX when using layout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In view, I define a JS function

```
function getTime() {
  $.ajax({
    url: '/Diseases/TellMeDate',
    success: function (data) {
      //alert("abc");
      $('#rData').html(data)
    },
      complete: function () {
      setTimeout(getTime, 1000);
    }
  })
}
```

After that, I call the `getTime` fuction

```
<div class="meta">
  <p id="rData"></p>
  <script>
    getTime();
  </script>
</div>
```

It works but only when I don’t call layout. If I call layout, it not work.

```
@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Chuẩn đoán bệnh";
  //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_PageLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Can anyone give me a solution?

Comment: Your `getTime()` is in layout or in your view?? and may be your layout loads all the scripts for your page and when you miss the layout scripts will not be loaded and you will `undefined error`!!  Check for any console errors!!

Comment: getTime() is in my view. I also don't know what it really did.

Comment: Did you check for any console errors?

Comment: i checked console error, but it have no request ajax has been called

Comment: can you post complete post!! I mean `TellMeDate` code and all the relevant codes??

Comment: ok, this is my full code

controller:

public string TellMeDate()
        {
            return DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }

Comment: Ok!! See I created your project!! and tested with and without layout!! It's working fine!! You might be missing something!! When I said relevant code I asked you to post the view and in view where you define your js function!! what and all scripts you have included etc. Sometimes the order might effect your functionality!!

Comment: Can you post a [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?